# Finite union of tail sigma-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}_i^j$  be a collection of sigma-algebras for 
$i \in \mathbb{N}$ and 
$j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{i+1}^j \subseteq  \mathcal{F}_i^j$ for all $i,j$. I would like to show that

$$\sigma\left(\cup_j\cap_i\mathcal{F}_i^j\right) = \cap_i\sigma\left(\cup_j\mathcal{F}_i^j\right)$$

but I'm not sure how, or whether it is true.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a research level question.  Try mathstackexchange.

Comment: It really was trivial before the edit - sorry.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What is $\sigma$?

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is "sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}$
What you want to show is false. Let $x^j_i$ and be a set of random variables, each taking values in $\{0,1\}$, where $j=1,2$ and $i=1,2,\ldots$. Let $\cF^j_i=\sigma(x^j_i,x^j_{i+1},\ldots)$.

Consider the event $A=$ "$x^1_i=x^2_i$ for all but finitely many $i$".

This event clearly belongs to the right hand side. To see that it does not belong to the left hand side, define the following probability distribution: let the $x^1_i$ be i.i.d uniformly in $\{0,1\}$. Then either let $x^2_i=x^1_i$ for all $i$ or let $x^2_i\ne x^1_i$ for all $i$, with probability $\frac12$ for either option.

Now, we see that the probability of $A$ is $\frac12$. However, the probability of any event in the lhs must be either 0 or 1, due to Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. Hence, $A$ does not belong to the lhs.

This question is related to a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8166/measurable-sets-not-depending-on-even-coordinates) of mine. I guess it is high time that I post the answer to that question too.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ori. I guess another way to see it is that the tail sigma-algebras of each sequence is trivial, while the tail of the sequence of pairs is not.

Comment: That's right, though I'm not sure why you call it "another way"...

Answer (score 0):

It's false. Let $n=2$. Suppose $A$ is some $\sigma$-algebra and $B$ is another $\sigma$-algebra strictly containing $A$. Let $\mathcal{F}_1^1=\mathcal{F}_2^2=A$ and $\mathcal{F}^j_i=B$, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I forgot another important condition. Sorry!

Comment: To clarify - this answer does not satisfy the updated conditions of the question.